# Onclick create input and save input value

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have several `span` and I want to handle onclick events. First, I want to create some elements on click event. Looks like this:

```
<div class="priceBox">
    Special Price:
    <input name="new-price" value="" />
</div>
```

Then user enters some numer and I want to save the `input` value to the attribute of `span` element, which was clicked.

```
<span name="1" data-price="input value" />
```

On second click on this `span`, will the `input` dissapear.

So far I have managed to create and remove `input` on click. But by clicking inside the `input` (when I want to type), makes the `input` disapear, because this is another click.

Maybe example from  JSFiddle will help to understand better what I want.
http://jsfiddle.net/0d17qp2L/

---

EDIT: I've updated @Ryan 's answer and put it to [JSFiddle again](http://jsfiddle.net/svtm1kpL/1/). It's much better but it still doesn't create `data-price` attribute with input value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend giving your priceBox divs a unique id that corresponds to the clicked span's name so that you can toggle it's visibility/existence.

```
$('span-selector').click(function(e) {
    var span = $(this);
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    var priceBox = $('div#priceBox'+ name);

    if ($(priceBox).length == 0) {
        priceBox = $('<div/>')
            .attr({'id':'priceBox'+name, 'class':'priceBox'})
            .text('Special Price: ')
            .append(
                $('<input/>')
                    .attr({'name':'new-price'})
                    .keyup(function(e) {
                        $(span).data({'price': $.trim($(this).val())});
                    })
            );
        $(span).append(priceBox);
    } else {
        $(priceBox).remove();
    }
});
```

You'll probably want to add some data validation to the input box's keyup function which I haven't done to prevent non-numeric values from being set in the data-price attribute of the span tag.

**EDIT**

If you NEED to see the data-price attribute in the source you can change out the following line:

```
$(span).data({'price': $.trim($(this).val())});
```

With this line:

```
$(span).attr({'data-price': $.trim($(this).val())});
```

Comment: Thanks :) I've changed your code a lite bit (there are some missing brackets too). It works, but still I can't see the data-price attribute. See the edit please.

Comment: When adding the data attribute in the way I have though jQuery you won't be able to see the attribute but you can access it via jQuery by calling $('span-selector').data('price'); I have fixed the bracket issues and added to my answer that should accomplish what you commented about.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I understand the question but I think you should add it to the parent of this.

If you change:

```
$(this).append(box);
```

To:

```
$(this).parent().append(box);
```

The box will not disapear if you click in it, but will disapear if you click on your items.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0d17qp2L/1/)

I hope this help! :)

Comment: That's good :) but the input value should be saved to the attribute of span which was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

i think this code will help you

js code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var inp = $('<input/>');
        $(inp).attr('type','text');
        $("body").append(inp);
        $("span").click(function(){
            $(inp).toggle();
            if($(inp).is(":hidden"))
                {
                    $("p").html("value entered is "+$(inp).val());
                }
            else
                {
                    $(inp).val("");
                }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

html code

```
<body>
<span>item1</span>
<span>item2</span>
<p></p>
</body>
```